# Inflate Android Menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have an activity with a ViewPager object (with two pages). The first page should not show any menu. But the second one should show a menu with one item.

The problem is, if I inflate the menu in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` with any menu.xml, everything work nice, I mean, the menu changes when I change the ViewPager's page ... but I don't want tho show any menu in the first page.

So, I thought not to inflate the menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu`(by this way, I will not show any menu in the first page, and I will inflate it when I show the second page), but if I don't inflate the menu in the `onCreateOptionsMenu`, the menu is not shown anymore!

Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.item_list_activity);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    if (position == 1) {
                        //Show user's menu
                        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                        inflater.inflate(R.menu.configure_users_menu, mMenu);

                    } else if (position == 0) {

                        //Clear menu. Don't show nothing.
                        mMenu.clear();

                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    //If I don't inflate the menu here, the menu does not inflate anymore.
    //If I inflate the menu here (with any menu), the menu works nice.
    /*MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.configure_groups_menu, menu);*/

    mMenu = menu;

    return true;
}
```

I've tried to use `menu.clear()` after inflate the menu in the `onCreateOptionsMenu`, but it does not work.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You can inflate a menu resource without any itens.

Comment: No, I've also try that. Using an empty menu is like don't inflate it.

Comment: You define the menu in the xml file, however, you don't need to include any <item>! I alredy used this many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be inflating menu's yourself, only do this in the onCreateOptionsMenu method.

**This is wrong:**

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if (position == 1) {
        //Show user's menu
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.configure_users_menu, mMenu);
    } else if (position == 0) {
        //Clear menu. Don't show nothing.
        mMenu.clear();
    }
}
```

I created a step by step guide on how to achieve the "per page menu". This method will automatically hide and show menu's per Fragment (page). (Assuming your mAppSectionsPagerAdapter contains Fragments)

**Step 1:**

Don't inflate any menu's in your Activity, but if you do those menu items will always be shown.

---

**Step 2:**

Call the `setHasOptionsMenu` method in the onCreate of the Fragment with the menu

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

---

**Step 3:**

Inflate the menu for the page (Fragment), do this inside the fragment code! Because the `setHasOptionsMenu` has been set to true the menu will be shown, but only if the fragment is active in the pager.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    //TODO Inflate menu here!
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

---

Full example code (Randomly googled): http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/Demonstrateshowfragmentscanparticipateintheoptionsmenu.htm

Comment: Thanks!! This is a so much better way to implement menus... Everyday you can learn something new!! ;) Thanks!